# Wait on a async call to webapi to complete from UI

Tags: .net, asynchronous, wait

I have a Webapi that does post action and posts to Database

```
public async Task<object> Post([FromBody]IEnumerable<Adjustment> adj)
{
           AdjustResponse response =  await  AdjustRepo.Post(adj);            
}
```

From UI I am making calls to this WebAPI

I have tried both

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/Adjustment/",
 Adju, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

and

```
response = client.PostAsync("api/Adjustment/", Adju, new     
JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

But after about a min or so I get the control back from the Webapi and the webapi still continues to post to database.

I need to show a validation summary to the Users saying posting is Complete.
Is there anyway I can have this UI wait for response

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is there maybe a timeout exception? How did you determine that the server continues executing when the client returns?

Comment: I have server in debug mode. Even though the control comes back i still see that the counter is getting incremented on my machine

Comment: Is there maybe a timeout exception? I still don't understand how you know that the server is not done yet. What counter are you speaking of? And what did the server return as a response?

Comment: i have added throw in every possible place. I run the webapi on my machine (in debug mode) then i run my web app in debug mode. I get the control back from webApi and see a stop at the break point in UI. The response is 502 error. But when i hit the pause button in webApi ( running on my machine) i get a stop at the break point there too.

Comment: 502 means the server is done serving the HTTP request. Maybe you started background work? Also, the request failed. Obtain the exception. Set your debugger to break on all exceptions. Post the ToString of that exception.